# Replace last character of string Oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, trim

How replace last character of string with blank if last character is dots.

Example:

```
Select replace('Luis Nazario Ronaldo Da Lima.',' ','.') as Name from dual
union all
Select replace('Ronaldo de Assis Moreira',' ','.') as Name from dual
```

From first name need remove dots at the end of string, second name is ok.

I need this resault:

```
LuisNazarioRonaldoDaLima
RonaldodeAssisMoreira
```

Comment: So - it seems that by "blank" you mean "nothing" (some people may think you mean "space", which would be highly unusual); and by "replace" you actually mean "remove". Right? Then - what if there are two or more dots at the end of the name, do you want to remove **all** those dots or just the last one?

Comment: Ugh... and do you really want to remove all the spaces from the names? I would think the output should look like `Luis Nazario Ronaldo Da Lima`. In any case, in words you said "second name is OK" but then in the "I need this result" you show the second name is not OK either - you removed all the spaces from it. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Luis Nazario Ronaldo Da Lima.', ' |\.$', '') AS Name FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Ronaldo de Assis Moreira', ' |\.$', '') FROM dual;
```

### Demo

This outputs:

```
LuisNazarioRonaldoDaLima
RonaldodeAssisMoreira
```

The regex pattern used here is `\.$`, and will target either spaces or the final character of the string if that final character be dot.

Comment: Why is your solution replacing spaces with spaces? (Regardless of anything else.) Also, from the OP's explanation, it is clear that by "blank" he means "nothing", not "space". Your solution will replace a trailing dot with a trailing space - not a very common requirement.

Comment: The OP changed the question after I had answered the original question, which did in fact ask for space as a replacement.

Comment: That is not true. Click on the **edited** link under his question, and point to where you see him asking for space as a replacement, in any version of the question. He did ask for "blank" all along, and from the very first version he said *From first name need remove dots at the end of string*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this. Regular expressions are a big machinery, resulting in slow(er) execution. They are great when you can't solve the problem with standard string functions, but that's not the case here.

To remove one, two, or more trailing periods at the end of a string, just use `RTRIM(..., '.')` Like this:

```
select original_name, rtrim(original_name, '.') as cleaned_up_name
from   (
         select 'Luis Nazario Da Lima.' as original_name from dual union all
         select 'Ronaldo de Assis Moreira'               from dual union all
         select 'Pele...'                                from dual
       )
;

ORIGINAL_NAME                 CLEANED_UP_NAME              
---------------------------   -----------------------------
Luis Nazario Da Lima.         Luis Nazario Da Lima 
Ronaldo de Assis Moreira      Ronaldo de Assis Moreira     
Pele...                       Pele
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first place the character to be replaced. like this:

```
Select replace('Luis Nazario Ronaldo Da Lima.','.') as Name from dual
union all
Select replace('Ronaldo de Assis Moreira','.') as Name from dual
```

But if you want to remove all dots in all lines with a variable on colunm name, you should do some like this:

```
select decode(substr(your_colunm, 0, LENGTH(your_colunm) - 1),
              '.',
              substr(your_colunm, 0, LENGTH(your_colunm) - 1),
              your_colunm) from your_table
```